# Table 'sample_portal.ip_collection' doesn't exist phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I've been trying to get the result of a `SELECT` statement but for some reason `PHP` returns this error: `mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter one to be resource, boolean given, which essentially means that my query doesn't work.
 So I executed it on the database and it returned a value just fine. I've ran this code `echo`mysql_error(); which returned: `<br>`Table 'sample_portal.ip_collection' doesn't exist. The thing is, it DOES exist. I've seen people restarting the SQL server and fixing it. This didn't work for me unfortunately.

Here's a little bit of code:

```
$ipcheck = $db->quote($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT address FROM ip_collection WHERE address = ". $ipcheck .";");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo mysql_error();
```

Code for the connection of my database:

```
function loginHandlerconnect()
{
        $db_host = "localhost";
        $db_username = "sampleuser";
        $db_password = "samplepassword";
        $db_name = "samplename";

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$db_host . ';dbname='. $db_name . '',$db_username,$db_password); 
        return $db; 
}
```

Comment: Where is your database connection code??

Comment: @Saty I'll edit my question for you

Comment: change `$db_name = "samplename";`  to `$db_name = "sample_portal";`

Comment: @Saty I've tried this, the page returns without css and inserts nothing. With the db name sample_name, inserts work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run the list tables command in PHP or execute `SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname` to see if yor table is there, this will make sure you are connected to the correct database and that the table is present

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Comment: My inserts work fine. Does that mean that I still have to check this?

Comment: it probably takes you about 30 seconds to check this out, if i were you, i would do all the debugging / checking i could do. Not ponder about what to test or not. Is the mysql_query() an overridden function? Or are you mixing the old mysql_query with PDO?